# I can not view the documents of the mongodb collection named daily-reports and can not drop the collecton

Tags: mongodb

I have imported a json file named `daily-report` to mongodb with the following command.

```
mongoimport -d mydb -c daily-reports --file D:\daily-reports.js
```

So I want to see the documents of theI collection with following code:

```
db.daily-reports.find()
```

But it give the following error message:

```
2016-07-21T09:34:57.266+0430 E QUERY    [thread1] ReferenceError: reports is not defined :@(shell):1:1
```

Please help me, how can I solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to view the data in collection daily-reports:

```
db['daily-reports'].find()
```

and for drop try this code:

```
db['daily-reports'].drop()
```

Answer (score 0):

If the mongodb collection name contain the '-' dash or hyphen symbol in it's name and you wont to apply any operation on that collection, mongodb will not recognize the parts of collection's name after the '-' dash or hyphen symbol. To solve this problem use angle brackets and single quotes as fallowing example.

To view the documents of collection use:

```
db['daily-reports'].find()
```

To drop the collection use:

```
db['daily-reports'].drop()
```